# How to filter objects in a array based on the properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

How can i filter objects in a array based on the objects properties?

I have this code right now:

```
products = [

    {
      title: "Bambu shorts 2.0"
    },
    {
      title: "Bambu shorts 2.0"
    },
    {
      title: "Bambu shorts 3.0"
    }
  ]

  uniqueProducts = [];

  $.each products, (i, el) ->
    if $.inArray(el.title, uniqueProducts) == -1
      uniqueProducts.push el
    return
```

I want to filter the array by the "titel" property of each object.
So if the title of the object already exists in the uniqueProducts array it should not add the object.

My code still pushes all three objects to the uniqueProducts array.

Thank you in advaced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for seen `title`.

```js
const
    raw_products = [{ title: "Bambu shorts 2.0" }, { title: "Bambu shorts 2.0" }, { title: "Bambu shorts 3.0"  }],
    uniqueProducts = raw_products.filter(
        (s => ({ title }) => !s.has(title) && s.add(title))
        (new Set)
    );

console.log(uniqueProducts);
```

Comment: Thank you! How do you write this in coffescript?

Comment: sorry, i have no idea of *coffescript*.

Comment: Where is "s" coming from?

Comment: `s` is a closure over the set and set by the call with `new Set` at the line below.

Comment: Ah! ok! Im still a little confused on how to write it in coffeescript but thanks anyway!